# Why is there a range error in the for loop?

Tags: python

```py
def frequency_analysis(string):
    count = 0
    freq_list = [
        [[" "] * len(string)],
        []
        ]
    print(freq_list[0])
    for i in range(len(string)):
        print(i)
        freq_list[0][i] = string[i]
        print(freq_list[0])
    return freq_list
print(frequency_analysis("fhfhffffj"))
print(frequency_analysis("jfjf"))
```

This is for a school assignment and I am not allowed to use built in functions other than `len()`. I am trying to make the `freq_list[0]` a list of separate characters from the string input. For some reason, after the first switch it turns the first list created into a list of just one item and then there is an out of range error. Can anyone explain why this is happening.

Input "fhh"
prints:

```
[" "," "," "]
0
"f"
1
Error
```

Comment: Please edit the question and add a example input and outputs to the questions. It makes it a lot easier for eveyone to debug.

Comment: @Tzane I did that, can you please have another look

Comment: Your explanation is ambiguous. Please show the expected output for the given inputs. Also, your code cannot possibly emit "Error"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At `freq_list[0]`, your are creating a nested list. You should either declare it with

```py
freq_list = [
    [" "] * len(string),
    []
    ]
```

if the nesting is unwanted, or assign values in it with

```py
freq_list[0][0][i] = string[i]
```

Here, with the two `[0]` indexing, you *do* access the inner list which you originally want to assign values within.

Answer (score 2):

#### 1. `[0] * 27`

- **Structure**: A flat list of 27 zeros.
- **Visualization**:

| Index | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |
| ... | 0 |
| 26 | 0 |

- **Use Case**: Ideal for initializing a list of counters or setting default values for a one-dimensional array.

#### 2. `[[0] * 27]`

- **Structure**: An outer list containing a single inner list of 27 zeros.
- **Visualization**:

| Outer Index | Inner List Value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | [0, 0, ..., 0] (27 elements) |

- **Use Case**: Suitable for starting a 2D matrix or list where you initially have one row, especially in scenarios requiring row-wise manipulation.

#### 3. `[[[0]] * 27]`

- **Structure**: A list of 27 elements, where each element is a list containing a single list with `0`.
- **Visualization**:

| Outer Index | Inner Lists |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | [[0]] |
| 1 | [[0]] |
| ... | ... |
| 26 | [[0]] |

- **Use Case**: Useful for initializing a 3-dimensional structure where each element is to be a complex nested list, starting with a single value. Ideal for scenarios where the third dimension will be dynamically populated.

#### 4. `[[[0] * 27]]`

- **Structure**: An outer list containing a single element, which is a list of 27 lists, each containing a single `0`.
- **Visualization**:

| Outer Index | Inner List containing 27 Lists with a single 0 each |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | [[0], [0], ..., [0]] (27 inner lists) |

- **Use Case**: This setup is geared towards creating a 3-dimensional data structure focusing on a single 2D layer or plane. It's a starting point for building more complex 3D structures where the initial layer is uniform.

Each of these configurations serves a distinct purpose, offering flexibility in how data structures are initialized and manipulated in Python. Understanding the dimensionality and nesting of lists is crucial for effectively managing data in applications that require complex, multi-dimensional data storage.

Comment: That edit works, the issue is the list needs to be a 2d list with a second list within it. This is only a part of the function thats giving me issue.

Comment: Bonus points for *explaining* how this answer addresses the question.

Answer (score -1):

Return freg-list is not reachable like with the others, when you start a loop it goes forever and when there is a loop all commands most remain reachable.
In this case, it's not reachable.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by `freq_list` "is not reachable"? Also, the loop clearly terminates based on the length of `string`.

Comment: What i mean by "is not reachable" is that the return can only be used within a function and it needs a if statement to work and it's not even aligned correctly.

Comment: In OP's code, `return` is used inside function `frequency_analysis()`. I can't see any issues with indentation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).